# Evento onkeyup com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando fazer o seguinte `onkeyup` de `inputs` que tenham a classe `virgula_nao`, obedeçam a função:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#virgula_nao', function () {
    valor_do_input = valor_do_input.value.replace(/,/gi, ".");}
});
```

Não sei como fazer isso. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você gostaria de fazer uma especie de mascara com ponto flutuante?

Comment: Qual é o problema? O que você quer que aconteça?

Comment: Explique melhor o que você deseja fazer, qual o comportamento esperado para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Eu quero que no formulário, se o usuario digitar , nos varios inputs que necessitam receber valor em moeda mude automaticamente para ponto. Consigo fazer com javascript, um input de cada vez... mas quero criar uma classe de inputs que obedecam essa condicao.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer substituir as vírgulas por pontos no evento [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), segue um exemplo de como fazer com **jquery**:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.virgula_nao', function(e) {
  var keycode = e.which ? e.which : event.keyCode;
  if (keycode == 110 || keycode == 188) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(",", "."));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Input 1: <input class="virgula_nao" /><br><br>
Input 2: <input class="virgula_nao" />
```

Comment: Exatamente isso... Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Não seria melhor partir para usar um plug-in de máscaras?

Você pode definir um pattern nos inputs.

Exemplo: `$('.money').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});`